# How does one count arguments to ejs.render()

Tags: node.js, ejs

Somewhat surprisingly, the following test code seems to work perfectly:

```
#!/bin/node
process.env.QUERY_STRING = "fname=doug";
var ejs = require("./node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs");
var querystring = require('querystring');
var content = "Hello, world.\n<%= arguments[0].fname %>\nGoodbye, world.";
console.log(ejs.render(content,querystring.parse(process.env.QUERY_STRING)));
```

My question comes in the next to the last line where I reference the `queryString` object as `arguments[0]`.

It would seem to me that that reference should be to `arguments[1]` since the queryString object is the **second** argument passed to `ejs.render`.

Can someone please explain to me why it's `arguments[0]` rather than `arguments[1]`?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You look inside `lib/ejs.js` file:

```
exports.render = function (template, d, o) {
  var data = d || {};
  var opts = o || {};

  // No options object -- if there are optiony names
  // in the data, copy them to options
  if (arguments.length == 2) {
    cpOptsInData(data, opts);
  }

  return handleCache(opts, template)(data);
};
```

it calls `handleCache`, inside of which You'll find that it returns function (lines: **169-173**):

```
func = exports.compile(template, options);
if (options.cache) {
  exports.cache.set(filename, func);
}
return func;
```

so in this case we have such calls:

```
handleCache(opts, template)(data)  =>  func(data)
```

so, that's why `data` is the first argument for `func`

p.s. why not just simply use: `require('ejs')` 
than `require("./node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs")` ?

cuz in `package.json` file of ejs it's already is: `"main": "./lib/ejs.js"`.

requiring file than package inside node_modules folder is not safe in case of in next release developer of package will decide to move code parts to different files.